# Pagination Loop Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a total novice and have come up with the following Google Script to send a GET Request and then parse the response into a Google Sheet.

I am only able to request 50 items on the first page and I have tried to search for a way to loop pages until I get all of the data that I requested.

I'm sure this is pretty easy if somebody could point me in the right direction? :-)

```
function myData1() {
  // Call the horizon API
  var url = "https://apc.hypaship.com/api/3.0/Orders.json?datefrom=27-03-2018T00:01";

  var headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
                 "remote-user": "Basic ****************************"};

  var options = {"method" : "get",
                 "headers" : headers};

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  var text = response.getResponseCode();

  Logger.log(response);

  // Parse the JSON reply
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  //Loop for data required
  for (i = 0; i <= data.Orders.Order.length - 1; i++) {
  var row = data.Orders.Order[i];
  var customer = row.Collection.CompanyName;
  var pcde = row.Collection.PostalCode;

  Logger.log(customer);
  Logger.log(pcde);

  //Export to Google Sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1,1).setValue([customer]);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 0,2).setValue([pcde]);}
}
```

{"Orders": {"AccountNumber": "279", "Messages": {"Code": "SUCCESS", "Description": "SUCCESS"}, "Pagination": {"TotalPages": "1", "NextPage": null, "PreviousPage": null, "ItemsPerPage": "50", "ItemsTotal": "4"},

[18-03-27 16:51:46:895 BST] {"Orders": {"AccountNumber": "279", "Messages": {"Code": "SUCCESS", "Description": "SUCCESS"}, "Pagination": {"TotalPages": "23", "NextPage": "2", "PreviousPage": null, "ItemsPerPage": "50", "ItemsTotal": "1121"},

Comment: If you're only able to get 50 results in any given request, then you'll need to issue another request as well. Most APIs allow supplying a page token of sorts, or an offset, etc, so you'll need to determine how to do this with your data source. Then you essentially use a `while` loop (if you can't know in advance how many to fetch) or a `for` loop (if you can get the total number of pages before starting). Once you indicate how your utilized API manages this type of request, we can offer suggestions on loop construction

Comment: I've just popped the first part of the JSON response at the bottom of my original post.  I guess I need a loop in relation to the pagination section!!   Keep requesting until NextPage=null?

Comment: Sounds right to me! You'll need to share a response where you have multiple pages in order to get any help from us though :) My thought is you will want a `do while` loop, e.g. `var data = {}; do { /* request code */ } while(data.Orders.Pagination.NextPage);`

Comment: Ha sorry I thought it would be better to show the response when there were no more pages!  Both are posted now.  I'm not sure how you guys keep sane minds as it is blowing mine although it is quite addictive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the API you are working with provides both the total number of pages, and the next page, you can use any loop structure you are comfortable with. Note, depending on time needed for these queries and whatever is done with their results, you may need to adopt a resumable approach.

In general, I recommend either the `do while` or explicit `for` loop approaches:

```
function doWhileExample() {
  var url = /* my api url */;
  var headers = ...;
  var options = ...;
  // An array of query parameters that are static for this particular request.
  var queryParams = [
    "datefrom=" + /* value of this param */,
    /* other params */
  ];
  var pageKey = /* the string keyword for specifying the result page for your API. Could be "page". */;
  var pageNum; /* could read a stored page number, e.g. from cache / properties service */

  // Execute your query / queries.
  var data = {}, output = [];
  do {
    var currentUrl = url + "?" + queryParams.join("&");
    if (pageNum) {
      currentUrl += "&" + pageKey + "=" + pageNum;
    }
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(currentUrl, options);
    var code = response.getResponseCode();
    /* do some error checking on the code e.g. don't try to parse data if the server is dead */

    // Store data for batch serialization after requests are done.
    // (Assumes you store "rectangular" data.)
    data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    for (var r = 0, rows = data.Orders.Order.length; r < rows; ++r) {
      var row = data.Orders.Order[r];
      output.push([row.Some.Data.One, row.Some.Data.Two, row.Some.Other.Data, ... ]);
    }
    // Update the page number.
    pageNum = data.Orders.Pagination.NextPage;
  } while (pageNum);

  // Serialize all data.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("someId").getSheetByName("someName");
  if (sheet && output.length && output[0].length) {
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1).offset(1, 0, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
  }
}
```

As hinted in the code above, you'll need to somehow indicate to the API url that you want a specific page, e.g. `&page=3` would work if it accepts those parameters in the url (and `page` is the right keyword) - it might want this kind of request manipulation in a header, etc.