# Pagination for Google Apps Script with Shopify API

Tags: api, google-apps-script, pagination, shopify-api

I am running into a bit of a snag setting up pagination in Google Apps Script. I am trying to use it for Shopify API. Reference links attached.

I attached the code below of what I have so far -

- trying to figure out how to use the "While" statement to make it check if there is a Next Page URL
- trying to figure out a way to parse the Link in the header. Example below. On pages 2+ there will be a next and previous link. We only need the next

  https://shop-domain.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-07/products.json?limit=50&page_info=eyJkaXJlY3Rpb24iOiJwcmV2IiwibGFzdF9pZCI6MTk4NTgyMTYzNCwibGFzdF92YWx1ZSI6IkFjcm9saXRoaWMgQWx1bWludW0gUGVuY2lsIn0%3D; rel="previous", https://shop-domain.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-07/products.json?limit=50&page_info=eyJkaXJlY3Rpb24iOiJuZXh0IiwibGFzdF9pZCI6MTk4NTgzNjU0NiwibGFzdF92YWx1ZSI6IkFoaXN0b3JpY2FsIFZpbnlsIEtleWJvYXJkIn0%3D; rel="next

  ```
    function callShopifyOrderCount() {
      var accessToken = 'xxxx';
      var store_url = 'https://xxxx.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-01/orders.json?status=any&fields=created_at,id,name,total-price&limit=20';
      var headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'X-Shopify-Access-Token': accessToken
      };
      var options = {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": headers,
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "muteHttpExceptions": true,
      }
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(store_url, options)
      // Call the link header for next page
      var header = response.getHeaders()
      var linkHeader = header.Link;
      var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
      var responseBody = response.getContentText();
      if (responseCode === 200) {
        var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);
        var objectLength = responseJson.orders.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < objectLength; i++) {
          var orderId = responseJson.orders[i].id;
          var orderPrice = responseJson.orders[i].total_price;
          var orderName = responseJson.orders[i].name;
        }
      } else {
        Logger.log(
          Utilities.formatString(
            "First Request failed. Expected 200, got %d: %s",
            responseCode,
            responseBody
          )
        );
        // ...
      }
      // *** NEED TO FIGURE OUT WHILE STATEMENT //
      while (Link != null) {
        var store_url = linkHeader;
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(store_url, options)
        var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
        var responseBody = response.getContentText();
        var header = response.getHeaders()
        var linkHeader = header.Link;
        if (responseCode === 200) {
          var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);
          var objectLength = responseJson.orders.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < tweetLength; i++) {
            var orderId = responseJson.orders[i].id;
            var orderPrice = responseJson.orders[i].total_price;
            var orderName = responseJson.orders[i].name;
          }
        }
        else {
          Logger.log(
            Utilities.formatString(
              "Second Request failed. Expected 200, got %d: %s",
              responseCode,
              responseBody
            )
          );
        }
      }
    }
  ```

References:
https://shopify.dev/tutorials/make-paginated-requests-to-rest-admin-api

https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/relative-pagination

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514904/pagination-loop-google-script)  help?

Comment: Personally, I like the do{}while() approach the first time through the loop your nextPageToken or link is null but that's okay as long there is a next on because it's only checked at the end of the loop.

Comment: I cannot understand about your current issue from your question. I apologize for this. So, can I ask you about the detail information of `I am running into a bit of a snag setting up pagination in Google Apps Script.`?